# MySQL get latest X rows, while ordering by column?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the latest X rows.  So I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT X
```

But I want to items to be returned ordered by column Y, where Y!=`date`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subselect

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT X)
ORDER BY Y
```

Comment: Unfortunately my web framework does not support this in Active Record.. so I'm using PHP to sort it (it's only 9 rows).